# Explain how and why the pointer has been used in the following turbo C code

Tags: c, pointers, turbo-c

```
int a[10],sum,*p;
sum=0;
for(p=&a[0];p<&a[10];p++)
    sum += *p;
printf("%d",sum)
```

Hi I'm new in turbo c, especially in pointers. Can someone please explain to me how the pointer was used in this program. Thank you in advance.

I know how the program works, but what I cannot understand is why did the program used a pointer and the '&' sign. Thanks.

Comment: You should consult a basic tutorial.

Comment: Start from this definition - *A pointer is a variable that holds an address of another variable in memory*.

Comment: If you have a choice, avoid Turbo C like the plague. It's ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an illustrative example of Pointers in C, However this code can also be written without using pointers.
Here

`p=&a[0]`

^ stores the memory address of the First value of the array `a`.
And the For loop will execute till the Pointer stores the memory address of the last Array value i.e. `a[10]`.

`sum += *p;`

^ in the above statement `*p` stands for the value of the memory address to which pointer `p` points to. For Example `p` currently points to `a[0]`. Then the Value of `a[0]` will be added to `sum`.
In the next iteration of the For loop, the value of `p` increases and it will point to `a[1]`.